# Macro with different font for subscript and superscript text

Tags: math-mode, macros

I need to define a macro, lets call it DifferentFontMacro, that takes a single string x as input. This string x is of the form `{string1}^{string2}\_{string3}`.
Now, I want the output of this macro to be `{string1}^{\mathsf{string2}}_{\mathsc{string3}}`. One approach that I could find is using the xstring package to extract `string1`, `string2` and `string3` from `x`, and then outputting the desired output. However, it seems cumbersome, and I don't know if there's a better solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Will you *always* have the subscript and superscript and in that specific order (superscript followed by subscript)? If so, one could use a delimited parameter text to extract the content...

Comment: do you mean `\mathsc` (which is not defined by default)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\zzz[1]{\zz#1}
\newcommand\zz[5]{{\mathrm{#1}}^{\mathsf{#3}}_{\mathit{#5}}}

\begin{document}


$\zzz{{string1}^{string2}\_{string3}}$

\end{document}
```